# Low memory / app getting crash?

Tags: ipad, low-memory

This is my code: -

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PageDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];//memory 55.7%
[self setPagesArray:mutableFetchResults];
[fetchRequest release];
[mutableFetchResults release];
```

I have released the memory but It is showing as low memory on this line/code

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];//memory 55.7%
```

please correct or suggest me, where I have done wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Seems to me that you're making a (mutable) copy of some potentially massive fetch result. If your fetch results include image data (which can be pretty big, especially at full resolution), that would absolutely crash your app.

Comment: Yes, It include images. What is the alternative for it?

Comment: Don't fetch images.  Or don't make mutable copies of the fetch results including images.  Or scale down the images so they are not full resolution.  Or only fetch the image when it's time to display and/or edit the record.

Comment: @Lion Michael already suggested you good approach.

Comment: Also - the leaks display shows you where the image that is being leaked is created, not the point of the actual leak.